# How to use Datatable Editor without ajax datasource?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I have a datatable that is populated from javascript. Here is an example:

```
    var row1 = ["blah","blah","40","10"];
    var row2 = ["bleh","bleh","54","23"];
    var dataSet = [];

    dataSet.push(row1);
    dataSet.push(row2);
    .
    .
    .

    table = $(tableId).DataTable({
    "data": dataSet,
    .
    .
```

I want to use inline editing, but i cannot get it to work with the data being populated in this way. Is this possible using Editor?

```
   editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: I DONT WANT AJAX,
    table: "#example",
```